# How to find out the days of the week an app is used in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Im trying to use the [app_usage](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage) flutter package to gather app usage statistics. I want to find out the days of the week the user uses each app but I'm not sure how to do this?

I've also opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/63) but I haven't had any response yet.

Here is my code so far:

```
 fetchAppUsage() async {
        AppUsage appUsage = new AppUsage();
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime.now();
        DateTime startDate =
            DateTime(endDate.year, endDate.month, endDate.day, 0, 0, 0);
        Map<String, double> usage = await appUsage.fetchUsage(startDate, endDate);

        usage.removeWhere((key, val) => val == 0);
        setState(() {
          apps = initUsage(usage);
          print('$apps : $times');
        });
        return apps;
      }
```

Currently it only gets the time in minutes.

```
initUsage(Map<String, double> usage) {
    List<Usage_Instance> _usage = List<Usage_Instance>();
    String result = '';
    usage.forEach((k, v) {
      String appName = k.split('.').last;

      String timeInMins = (v / 60).toStringAsFixed(2);
      result += '$appName : $timeInMins minutes\n';

      Usage_Instance usage_model =
          Usage_Instance(app: appName, duration: timeInMins);
      _usage.add(usage_model);

      setState(() {
        _usageList = _usage;
      });
    });
    return result;
  }
```

The output looks like this:

> nexuslauncher, duration: 102.92

The wanted output:

Chrome : 14 minutes at 02/12/2020, 13:00pm

Any help would be appreciated.